# Largest eigenvalue of symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

I am trying to understand why the $\lambda_{\max}$ function is convex given an $n\,x\,n$ symmetric matrix, let's call it $A$. I know from elementary property of eigenvalues that all the eigenvalues of $A$ must be real.

If the entries of $A$, $A_{ij}$, are convex, does that simplify the question?

EDIT: The entries of the matrix depend convexly on some input vector, if that was not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$λ_{\max}(A)=\sup_{\|v\|\le 1} f_v(A)$ with $f_v(A)=v^TAv$

is the supremum over a family of linear functions, which means it is also a family of convex functions, it inherits the property of convexity.

However, you should be careful in defining what it means that a matrix valued function $x\mapsto A(x)$ is convex. What would be the epigraph of the function?