# Maximal eigenvalue is a convex function. Why?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a symmetric real matrix. Let $f(A)=\lambda_{\max}(A)$ be its largest eigenvalue. Why is $f$ convex?

Comment: What is your definition of convex function?

Comment: This follows from the [min-max theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)

Comment: More generally one has the Weyl inequalities, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory.  And then, there is the Horn problem ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest eigenvalue of symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687001/largest-eigenvalue-of-symmetric-matrix)

Answer (score 16):

$f(A) = \sup_{\|x\|=1} x^T Ax$, and a supremum of convex functions is convex.

(For a given $x$, the function $A \mapsto x^TAx$ is linear, hence convex.)

Comment: You are right, feel free to roll back the edit. It is the domain that has to be convex, not the index set. I realized it soon after but left as is since the norm formula works either way.

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$f(A) I - A\succeq 0$, $f(B)  I - B \succeq 0$ implies $(\lambda f(A) + (1- \lambda) f(B))I - ( \lambda A + (1-\lambda) B) \succeq 0$

Comment: Just Courant-Fischer in disguise

Comment: it would help to know what the notation $\succeq$ means

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\lambda_{\max}(A) = \min\{ t : t\geq h, h \in S(A) \}$$

where

$$S(A)=\{h:h\geq \langle A, xx^T\rangle \text{ , }\forall x \in R^n \text{ and } x^Tx=1\}$$

The set $S(A)$ is convex. This is a convex function since $\min$ is a convex function on a convex set. So the function is convex.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the answer.