# Convexity of Maximal Eigenvalue of Nonsymmetric Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, hermitian-matrices

There are multiple similar questions, but I can't find any good news on this special case. I'm afraid the answer may just turn out to be, "Sorry, you're just out of luck", but I've got to ask.

I've got a multi-body spring-mass system with $n$ masses, $n$ springs, and *no* dampers. This is a time-invariant linear dynamical system:
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = Ax
\end{equation}

The matrix $A$ is tridiagonal, and all its off-diagonal elements are positive. $A$ is itself parametrized as an affine combination of sparse tridiagonal matrices. Denote the coefficients of the affine combination by the vector $z$.

\begin{equation}
A = \sum_i A_i z_i
\end{equation}

The eigenvalues of $A$ are all real. They're all negative. They will always be so, because each eigenvalue is the negative of the square of one of the fundamental frequencies of vibration. There is no damping. We want to modify $z$ to find an $A$ with desirable spectral characteristics. In particular, we are interested in the following optimization problem.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\textrm{minimize} & c^T z \\
\textrm{w.r.t.} & z,\\
\textrm{s.t.} & \lambda_{\max}(A) &\leq& r,\\
& z_{\min} - z &\leq& 0.
\end{array}
\end{equation}

*Unfortunately*, $A$ is not symmetric. If we restrict ourselves to the case where *all* the masses and springs are the same, then everything is good, $A$ is symmetric, $\lambda_\max$ is convex in $z$, and we're done. In the general case, $A$ is not symmetric, but I'm still hopeful.  There's *so* much structure here, *something* should work out. It's like a question from one of Steve Boyd's take-home finals.

Surely there must be some little concession, some cute trick, something I'm missing. Is this spectral constraint at least quasi-convex? If we're guaranteed that the eigenvalues remain real, then what's so special about symmetry?

Hoping someone has an a-ha moment.

p.s.: unfortunately Michael Grant does not appear to be a tag.

Comment: The system is $\dot{x} = A x$, and $A$ is $t$-parametrized. But $t$ is a parameter, not the variable w.r.t. which the "dot" derivative is taken. And it seemed perverse to say $\dot{x} = A(t) x$ which is canonical notation for a time-variant system, when the system is not. I'll update the question for clarity.

Comment: Notation updated. $t$ is a vector, each $t_i$ is a scalar, each $A_i$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, as is $A$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are all real.

Comment: Done. $t$ is only used for time. If I want to maximize the scalar $p$ such that the largest eigenvalue of the 2 X 2 matrix $[p\; 0; 0\; p/2]$ is 4, then the solution to that problem is $p = 4$. I just have a slightly more complicated case.

Comment: There's also this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Similarity_to_symmetric_tridiagonal_matrix
Looks like the optimization problem is not convex in $z$ after all. But it might be possible to solve a conservative approximation using the relationship between geometric and arithmetic means.

Comment: @Royi The maximal eigenvalue of a generic non-symmetric matrix is not guaranteed to be convex.

Comment: @Royi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329189/maximal-eigenvalue-is-a-convex-function-why

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed a convex problem. The tridiagonal matrix can be made symmetric via a [special similarity transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Similarity_to_symmetric_tridiagonal_matrix). The equation

$A = \sum_i A_i z_i$

is replaced with another equation in the same variables with symmetric matrices:

$S = \sum_i S_i z_i.$

With that, this is a straightforward problem with a single linear matrix inequality, or, if your optimizer supports it, a max. eigenvalue constraint.